# if statement doen't run even though the console.log before that shows the statement should run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to turn a javascript property true. I check first in the console if the if statement should run or not. According to, it should. I am sure I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

In the console it is the same id.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
//Selects the current HTMl element and gets its id
let questionId = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');

for (let i in wholeSurvey['formCategories']) {
    let cat = wholeSurvey['formCategories'][i];
    let catId = cat.id;

    for (let question in cat['formQuestions']) {
        question = cat['formQuestions'][question];
        console.error('question.id: ', question.id, 'questionId: ', questionId);

        if (question.id === questionId) {
            console.log('Hi');
            question.done = true;
            console.info(question);
        }
    }

    cat = wholeSurvey['formCategories'][i]['formQuestions'];

    if ($(cat).last()[0].done === true) {
        console.log($(cat).last());
        $("#A" + catId).css('background-color', '#46AD58').text('');
    }
  }
});
```

I expect it to turn the done properthy of question to true, but for now nothing changes and it entirely "skips" the if statement.

All help is welcome, sorry for grammar and spelling mistakes.

Comment: present your html code

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, nobody can reliably duplicate what you're seeing.

Comment: `questionId` is a string and I suspect `question.id` is an integer, in which case `question.id === questionId` will never be true.

Comment: @Nick You are correct, I'm an idiot sometimes

Comment: @SilkeNL we've all done it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

questionId was indeed a string like @Nick said in the comments. I used parseInt () to make questionId a number. I used this site:
[gomakethings.com](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/)